# Zend framework2 URL Rewriting

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting, zend-framework2

The url for user profile in my zf2 application is:

```
http:/mywebsite/profile/index/index/457/
```

here 457 is id of the user(say rogger_federer).

I want my url to look like this(by fetching username from database using id in url)

```
 http:/mywebsite/profile/rogger_federer
```

my htaccess file is

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

What changes i need to do in .htaccess file?

Please help .I'm new to zend and dont have that much knowledge of htaccess and patterns.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically not something you can do in the .htaccess, because you need to look into your DB.

What's happening when you receive the request is that it is going through your htaccess first, and then in the router. Your routing configuration is in your module configuration file.

What you have to do then is to change your route from profile/index/index/457/ (probably a default route, could you quote your config file for more information) to something accepting profile/rogger_federer (that would be a segment route /profile/:username with a constraint for username:([AZ-az_]*) and no default. This route has to send you to a controller where you lookup in the db and fetch the user based on the username.

You also need to make sure username has a unique constraint, and it is sluggable/slugged (sanitized for url).

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a slug based on the users username and save this to the users DB record.

You could use an Alnum filter for this for example and then replace whitespace with hyphen or underscore.

You would then need to create an index on this 'slug' field and use this index when querying the DB for the users record rather than the ID (which will no longer be available from the URL)

The slug in the URL, should be configured as a route param in your routing config and you can easily access it in your controller action using the params() plugin:

```
$slug=$this->params('slug');
$userRepository->findBySlug($slug);
```

ref : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-params-plugin

Routing Example:

```
'update' => 

['type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment','options' => 
    ['route' => '/profile/:slug','constraints' => 
        ['id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'],'defaults' => 
            ['controller' => 'User','action' => 'profile',
                                      ]
                                   ]
                                ]
```

Reference:

ZF2 Routing : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html